# GWT Date Time Component

Tags: user-interface, gwt, datetimepicker

Is there a GWT Date Time Component?

Note: I am already making use of the Date - Calendar component.

I want to have time as an additional input.

Comment: Read the official FAQ @ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stack-overflow-work-the-official-faq if you don't understand how the site works... and don't shout, please.

Comment: And could you specify what exactly you want - a Date/Time widget (for the user to select date/time) or a class for manipulating time?

Comment: date/time widget ofcourse! 
And shout!? when did i do that!

Comment: of course you can read the FAQ, but I can tell you: 1) someone voted your question because he/she thinks it's interesting; it works as recognizement (you will get reputation points) 2) I think Igor is talking about using "!", he thinks you are shouting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what I wanted, the Date Time Calendar Picker is right now in the Incubator. 
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean your using the GWT [DatePicker](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DatePicker.html) widget or you are looking for something like that?